# HTML text goes long and creates Horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html

I have to add a text value dynamically in a `div` tag of a HTML page. but if this text is too long then it doesn't stay in its `div` width which I have assigned as `500px`, but goes straight long in a single row and this makes the Web page to have a horizontal scroll. What should I do to fix the length of this text. I don't mind if it increases number or rows.

Here is the Css:

```
.question
{
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;

}
.answer
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    overflow: auto;

}
#main
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

Here is the JS code:

```
function create_div_dynamic(answer){

     var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
     dynDiv.id = "divDyna"+counter;

     var question_data = question();
     var answer_data= answer();
     dynDiv.innerHTML="<div id='main'  ><div class='question'> "+question_data+" </div> <div class='answer'> "+answer_data+"</div> </div>"
     dynDiv.style.height = "auto";
     dynDiv.style.width = "auto";     
     dynDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
     document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
     counter=counter+1;


    }
```

Comment: You can use <br /> to enter the next row.

Comment: I cant use that as the whole text will be generated dynamically

Comment: Please post your css/html as we can only guess if you don't.

Comment: Tried overflow hidden but it hides the text which is in access to the width set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the rule word-wrap in css:

ie:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Although this is CSS3 and may not be supported in all browsers.

Comment: And make sure that you didn't have `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` breaks words, with no regard to acceptability by the rules of languages or notations. It is meant to be used as emergency, not as a regular device.

Comment: Yes but if it is just a hash then you can use this just fine, keeping in mind that older browsers dont support this.

Comment: @svenbravo7, the content was described as “text”, not “hash”, and the class names suggests that it is questions and answers, apparently in some natural language(s).

Comment: It's better to use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` which is the new name for break-word css property. More info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use style="width:20px;" that will size your div to 20px. If no spaces exist though, the div will automatically size to the length of the largest work. If you want to hide(make div exactly the size you need it) words longer  than the size of your dive you can use `width:20px;overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

hy add this style in your div.

`<div style="width=500px; display: inline-block; text-align: justify;"> text </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the content of the text, as well as style sheets being applied, to see what prevents normal word wrapping, and remove the cause or deal with the consequences.